# V-model with boostrap-vue b-table

Tags: javascript, vue.js, bootstrap-vue

Im trying bind v-model by passing the value inside the items array. But binding doesn't happen correctly..
The ultimate goal here is to use a store..all these values are used across multiple "wizard" components.


If I give v-model a value directly it works. for example `v-model="income"`, however i need it to bind each to different data sources. So i tried to pass it in from the object categories with a property fieldName

```
<b-table striped hover :items="categories" >
    <template v-slot:cell(Adjustments)="data">
      <textInput
        v-model="data.item.fieldName"
        ></textInput>
     </template>
</b-table>
```

here i also tried to pass the fieldNames as a string "income", currently income as is isn't defined.

```
export default {
    components:{ textInput },
    computed:{
        income:{
            get(){
               return  this.incomeTotal
            },
            set(value){
                this.incomeTotal = value
            }
        },
        rent:{
            get(){
               return  this.rentTotal
            },
            set(value){
                this.rentTotal = value
            }
        }
    },
 data:function() {
        return {
            rentTotal:'1.00',
            incomeTotal :'4.00',
 categories:[
            { "Category":'Income', "Your Amount": '$0.00','fieldName':income},
            { "Category":'Rent', "Your Amount": '$0.00','fieldName':rent},
          ]
        }
}
```

Any tips on how to get this to work, or suggestions on a different / better way to achieve my goal?

Comment: You want pass `:items` to `b-table` base on condition?

Comment: not quite, im trying to set ```v-model = fieldName``` for each item in the categories array. so in this case.. there will be two input fields 1 with ```v-model=income```, the other with ```v-model = rent```

Comment: So you want to pass an array to `v-model` that is concat of two array? and their name is store in `fieldName` property?

Comment: no not an array..the ```fieldName``` property represents the objects with get/set inside ```computed```..

Comment: I got that, Now you want to set v-model base on `fieldName`?

Comment: yeah thats right

Answer (score 2, accepted):

here is my solution:

use `:value` instead of using `v-model`, then using `@change` or `@input` to change your data:

```
<b-table striped hover :items="categories" >
    <template v-slot:cell(Adjustments)="data">
      <textInput
        :value="getValue(data.item.fieldName)"
        @input="change(data.item.fieldName, $event.target.value)"
        ></textInput>
     </template>
</b-table>

export default {
  components: { textInput },
  computed: {
    income() {
      return this.incomeTotal;
    },
    rent() {
      return this.rentTotal;
    }
  },
  data: function() {
    return {
      rentTotal: "1.00",
      incomeTotal: "4.00",
      categories: [
        { Category: "Income", "Your Amount": "$0.00", fieldName: income },
        { Category: "Rent", "Your Amount": "$0.00", fieldName: rent }
      ]
    };
  },
  methods: {
    getValue(property) {
      return this[property];
    },
    change(property, value) {
      this[property] = value;
    }
  }
};
```

Comment: Think this might be the best solution, but i think you have a few minor errors in the code. The `fieldName` property values should be a string. I think you meant to call the method `getValue` and not `setValue` (since it returns the value). and you might've misspelt "property" as "propery" in your two methods.

Comment: @Hiws the ```fieldName``` was a copy and paste from my code. But, it was something i tried passing it as an object and string both. Looks like BeHappy left it as is. But yes, they need to be strings. so..```{"fieldName":"income"}```

Also.. ```$event.target.value``` throws a ***no value property error***. just need to pass ```$event```. Even though this works. I would like to know why v-model doesn't work.

Comment: It's because you can't reference a computed property or data property inside data. (since neither exists at that point). And even if you moved it initiate your categories in a `mounted` hook, you would not be able to pass in a reference to a computed property, you would only pass in the value.

Answer (score 1):

If anyone is interested, I already had a solution with blur event. But was hoping to get v-model working...

```
<div>
    <b-table striped hover :fields="categoriesFields" :items="categories"  thead-class="alert-success  alert">
        <template v-slot:cell(Adjustments)="data">
            <textInput
            @blur="blur"
            :value="value(data.item.fieldName)"
            :name="data.item.fieldName"
            ></textInput>
        </template>
    </b-table>
</div>
```

```
export default {
    components:{ textInput },
    data: function(){
        categories:[
                { "Category":'Income', "Your Amount": '$0.00','fieldName':"income"},
                { "Category":'Rent', "Your Amount": '$0.00','fieldName':"rent"},
         ],
    },
   methods:{
    blur: function(e){
            console.log(e['srcElement'].name);
            console.log(document.getElementsByName(e['srcElement'].name)[0].value)
        },
   },
}
```